# Codeigniter check if LoggedIn in the index.php file

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I realy need a help, I'm seeking for solution by myself 2 days ago but no result.
I need to check if the user is loggedIn using:

$CI =& get_instance();
   $loggedIn = $CI->session->userdata('loggedin') == TRUE

If $loggedIn is true that mean the user is logged In. I need to check this in the index file because i choose the database from this :

```
$parsed = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$path = $parsed['path'];
$path_parts = explode('/', $path);
$db = $path_parts[4]; 


if(isset($db) && is_numeric($db)){
    define('DB', $db);
}
```

$db is the name of my database so if i'm in the login page there is no probleme because it's set and numeric in the url. but when im logged in i store this $db in session variable so i need to do this test :

```
if($this->session->userdata('loggedin') == TRUE){
    define('DB', $this->session->userdata('db'));
}
```

My database file :

```
   $active_group = 'default';
   $active_record = TRUE;
   $db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
   $db['default']['username'] = '*********';
   $db['default']['password'] = '*********';
   $db['default']['database'] = DB;
   $db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
   $db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
   $db['default']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
   $db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
   $db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
   $db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
   $db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
   $db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
   $db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
   $db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
   $db['default']['stricton'] = TRUE;
```

The mean probleme is that i need to use a different database via the url. if a user enter this link for example : /user/login/34 he will use the database named 34.

I'm using codeigniter php framework
Code of core/MY_Controller.php

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller
{
    public $data = array();
    function __construct ()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->data['errors'] = array();
        $this->data['app_name'] = config_item('app_name');
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->load->model('user_m');

        $db_prefix = 'autojahi_dev';
        $config = array(
           'hostname' => 'localhost',
           'username' => '****',
           'password' => '****',
           'database' => '****',
           'dbdriver' => 'mysql',
           'dbprefix' => '',
           'pconnect' => FALSE,
           'db_debug' => TRUE,
           'cache_on' => FALSE,
           'cachedir' => 'cache',
           'char_set' => 'utf8',
           'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
           'swap_pre' => '',
           'autoinit' => TRUE,
           'stricton' => TRUE
        );

        if($this->uri->segment(4)){
               $config['database'] = $this->uri->segment(4);
        }          

      $this->load->database($config);
      //$this->db->reconnect();//shouldnt be required but try it if there is problem
      echo $this->db->database;//for testing 


        $current_link = uri_string();

        // Algorithm of autojahiz access autorization

        $allow_not_loggedin = array('login', 'logout', 'reset_pass', 'send_reset_pass_email', 'reset_pass_form', 'update_pass', 'views', 'invalid_link' );

        switch (strtolower( $this->router->class ) )
        {
            case 'user':
                $allow_loggedin = array('denied', 'index', 'edit', 'logout');
            break;

            case 'dashboard':
                $allow_loggedin = array('denied', 'index');
            break;
        }

        if ( $this->session->userdata('loggedin') == FALSE ) 
        {   
            if (!in_array( $this->router->method, $allow_not_loggedin) )
            {
                redirect( 'user/login' );
            }
        }
        else
        {   
            if (!in_array( $this->router->method, $allow_loggedin ) )
            {
                //redirect( 'user/denied' );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand eveything. Depending on the user, you will connect to a different database ? How many db have you ? Why in index.php, you can declare all your db in your config file and then pick the one you need on your models's constructor.

Comment: I want to use a different database via the url, For example for this url : /user/login/56 the system must use the database named 56

Comment: The probleme is that i need to use a different database via the url. if a user enter this link for example : /user/login/34 he will use the database named 34. i cant found how to resolve this

Comment: CodeIgniter has the URI helper so you dont need to do the parsing yourself. CI will be much more robust. You can access like `$this->uri->segment(4);`

Comment: @MikeMiller, because the uri library is not loaded yet !

Comment: I get error when i use $this->uri->segment(4); in index file. I use it like that : $CI =& get_instance();
 $CI->load->library('uri');
 $db = $CI->uri->segment(4);

Comment: If you have a CI object then load the library. You shouldnt need to mess around doing this in the index.php file this is not correct approach. Change your db on the fly in your model by passing the uri element as an argument to your model

Comment: Is it possible your database name in database.php is the same as in the $config array? If so I would change the segment index as you might not have 4 segments in your URI

Comment: THe same probleme if i change the name of the database in database.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this in your controller. For ease you can create an extension file called `MY_Controller.php` in the application/core folder and extend to your controllers like

`class Other_controller extends MY_Controller{}`

In application/core/MY_Controller.php construct function do..

```
class MY_controller extends CI_Controller{

  public function __construct() {

   parent::__construct();

   $config = [
   'hostname' => '',
   'username' => '',
   'password' => '',
   'database' => 'defaultdb',
   'dbdriver' => 'sqlsrv',
   'dbprefix' => '',
   'pconnect' => TRUE,
   'db_debug' => TRUE,
   'cache_on' => FALSE,
   'cachedir' => APPPATH .'cache',
   'char_set' => 'utf8',
   'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
   'swap_pre' => '',
   'autoinit' => TRUE,
   'stricton' => FALSE
  ];

  if($this->uri->segment(4)){
       $config['database']=$this->uri->segment(4);
  }          

  $this->load->database($config);

  $this->db->reconnect();//shouldnt be required but try it if there is problem

  echo $this->db->database;//for testing 

}
```

Comment: You get me here, But why i get error when i use this in MY_Controller? i have to create an other controller?

Comment: You put MY_Controller in the application/core folder?

Comment: I have a probleme the app still using the configuration of config/database.php file

Comment: Turn database autoload off. To check which database you are using just echo $this->database

Comment: Yes i put if in core folder, Now it don't show errors when i replace $config =  [ by $config = array( But the probleme now is that the app still using the configuration of config/database.php

Comment: I turn it off in config/autoload.php file what i have now is this config : $autoload['libraries'] = array('session');
 but i have the same probleme it still using the config of config/database.php file

Comment: can you print the contents of $config out before you pass it into `$this->load->database($config)`

Comment: This is my config array :  $config = array (
   'hostname' => '',
   'username' => '',
   'password' => '',
   'database' => 'defaultdb',
   'dbdriver' => 'sqlsrv',
   'dbprefix' => '',
   'pconnect' => TRUE,
   'db_debug' => TRUE,
   'cache_on' => FALSE,
   'cachedir' => APPPATH .'cache',
   'char_set' => 'utf8',
   'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
   'swap_pre' => '',
   'autoinit' => TRUE,
   'stricton' => FALSE
  );

Comment: And if you do `echo $this->database;` straight after `$this->load->database($config);`?

Comment: It cause an error. but when i use echo $this->db->database it show me the database name mentionned in database.php file. So how can this probleme be resolved?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it show an error : Unable to load the requested class: database

Comment: You dont need to load the library seperately. my mistake. You will need to use valid db credentials or it will return an error

Comment: All database credentials are valid but still use the config of config/database.php

Comment: You will have to post your code. I have tested the above 5 mins ago and works fine if the database credentials in the $config array are valid.

Comment: I edited my post by putting MY_Controller.php file content. all db credentials are valid but it still use the config in config/database.php

Comment: Whats your controller code look like? are you definately extending MY_Controller.php ?

Comment: The probleme is where i load session library the app use the config in config/database.php but when i don't use session library it's fine, the configuration loaded is the configuration in MY_Controller. Any idea??

Comment: I dont understand. If your $config has the same database name as database.php then its hard to tell if its trying to switch on the fly. The solution you have will work you just need to debug. Maybe you can load teh session library after this rather than in autoload

Comment: Now i empty the hole file (config/database.php) but when i load session in the top of the script that you give me. It show this message : No database connection settings were found in the database config file. it's like if when i use session the app search for database.php params. Can you test this in your codeigniter code please?

Comment: The probleme is that i need to do condition by session. if user is logged in the database name will be retrieved from session variables but if the user is not logged in the database name will be retrieved from segment(3); @Mike Miller Can you help me?

Comment: I found where is the probleme. session musn't use database. Problem resolved. So i can sleep this night hahaa.

Comment: Ahhh yes that would cause problem. Would need to hack about with session class to be able to use multiple dB's does not sound doable. Glad got it solved in the end

Comment: Thank you. There is a way to use database session on. And run my code without problems? A hook or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it is exactly what you need, but here is how I would have done that :

In application/core, create MY_Loader.php

```
class MY_Loader extends CI_Loader
{

    public function database($params = '', $return = FALSE, $query_builder = NULL)
    {
        // Grab the super object
        $CI =& get_instance();
        $CI->load->library('session');

        $db_name = "mydefault_db";
        if($CI->session->userdata('db'))
            $db_name = $CI->session->userdata('db');

        $params['hostname'] = "localhost";
        $params['username'] = "root";
        $params['password'] = "";
        $params['database'] = $db_name;
        $params['dbdriver'] = "mysqli";
        $params['dbprefix'] = "";
        $params['pconnect'] = FALSE;
        $params['db_debug'] = TRUE;
        $params['cache_on'] = FALSE;
        $params['cachedir'] = "";
        $params['char_set'] = "utf8";
        $params['dbcollat'] = "utf8_general_ci";

        // Do we even need to load the database class?
        if ($return === FALSE && $query_builder === NULL && isset($CI->db) && is_object($CI->db) && ! empty($CI->db->conn_id))
        {
            return FALSE;
        }

        require_once(BASEPATH.'database/DB.php');
        if ($return === TRUE)
        {
            return DB($params, $query_builder);
        }

        // Initialize the db variable. Needed to prevent
        // reference errors with some configurations
        $CI->db = '';

        // Load the DB class
        $CI->db =& DB($params, $query_builder);
        return $this;
    }
}
```

And then in the controller :

```
public function login($db_id)
{
    $this->session->set_userdata('db', $db_id);

    //Your stuff here

    //let's suppose we have a flag for the login success
    if(!$logedin)
        $this->session->unset_userdata('db');
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Wait i will test it now and put a comment. Wait a moment please

Comment: It show error : Message: Undefined property: User::$session in line $CI->session->userdata('db')

Comment: Is session library set in autoload ?

Comment: Yes is set in autoload

Comment: Please add `$CI->load->library('session');` After `$CI =& get_instance();`

Comment: Weird, I tested it in a fresh CI install and it worked correctly. There is something you do that I don't.

Comment: The only probleme here is that session library or uri library can't be load. I can't use $CI->uri->segment(); too

Comment: Session lib can be load, I actually did it. What codeigniter version are we talking about ?

Comment: Codeigniter Version 2.1.2

Comment: I just updated to the last version. I copied the system folder and i replaced the old one

Answer (score -1):

If I were you, I'll define all databases that will be used like following :

```
$db[30] = array(
    'hostname' => '',
    'username' => '',
    'password' => '',
    'database' => '',
    'dbdriver' => 'sqlsrv',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => TRUE,
    'db_debug' => TRUE,
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => APPPATH .'cache',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'autoinit' => TRUE,
    'stricton' => FALSE
);

$db[32] = array(
    'hostname' => '',
    'username' => '',
    'password' => '',
    'database' => '',
    'dbdriver' => 'pdo',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => TRUE,
    'db_debug' => TRUE,
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => APPPATH .'cache',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'autoinit' => TRUE,
    'stricton' => FALSE
);
$active_group = SELECTED_DB;
```

And then I'll use Hook to define `SELECTED_DB`, or in the `default_controller` :

```
if($this->session->userdata('loggedin') == TRUE){
    define('SELECTED_DB', $this->session->userdata('selecdb'));
}
else{
   $selected_db = $this->uri->segment(2); // or use $this->input->get('db');
   $this->load->database($selected_db);
   defined('SELECTED_DB') 
      || define('SELECTED_DB', $selected_db);

   // Do login
}
```

Comment: I have more than 68 database i can't define them in a file, the idea that i found is when the user is not loggedin i select the database from the $_GET ($this->uri->segment) and if logged in the database will be selected from session variables

Comment: @AhmedFaiçal, When the user access to the `default_controller` and he is not logged in, you redirect him to the login page, right ? so how can you tell which database to use ?

Comment: why cant you define the 68 databases in a file?

Comment: That what i need, I need that user choose the database via url. Once chosen. He can access to the website and logged in the url will be like this '/user/login/56' 56 is the name of database. that i will retrieve from url and define it like a global variable 'DB' but the probleme is when the user is logged in. the link will be changed and i cant retrieve database from url and the global variable 'DB' will be empty

Comment: @MikeMiller I cant define 68 databases because i ignore how much database i will have in the future. it my be more than 600

Comment: Riiight.. i get you. You are asking is how to change just the database name. I will add an answer